# Is there a techical name for these unpolarized AC cables?

Tags: ac, identification, cables

These are unpolarized cables found in household appliances and some laptop power bricks. Do they have a technical name?

In this photo, the cable on the left actually has a larger end to it, and is white different from the one on the right. Do these kinds of plugs follow some formal standard, loosely or otherwise?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The left one looks unusual to me. All C7 i have seen, look like the one on the right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [IEC-60320](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320) standard, those are "C7" plugs.
[image]
The mating socket in the appliance is a "C8".
This style of plug is also often colloquially known as a "figure-8" plug.

Although the body where you grip on your pair of examples is different, you should find that the part of the plug which actually inserts into the equipment is the same. You could probably plug the smaller one into the appliance which the larger one belongs to, but the larger body of the other one might prevent you from plugging it into the appliance which the smaller one came from.

Comment: The issue with the smaller plug in the larger socket is that it's a loose fit is causing sounds of arcing if the plug is jostled. This can't be healthy. Is there any name for the thicker plug and socket?

Comment: @Zhro If you're looking for anything more specific than "non-standard variant of IEC-60320 C7", you're going to be disappointed. Although I suppose we can't really tell from this information if it's the larger one or the smaller one that's nonstandard.

Comment: @Zhro are you sure the plug is fully inserted into the socket? Many such plugs including the common C5/C6 and C13/14 have the issue that it can work even if not fully inserted, but will be unreliable in that situation. If it's loose even when fully inserted that means one of the two is not standard (or maybe exceeded its design life in terms of number of connections/disconnections). You can then start by trying a new cable, those are extremely easy to find and cost a few bucks (or you probably have quite a few at home already).

Comment: If both are fully inserted, **with the other end unplugged** do you have calipers to measure the size of the holes?  I would not just unplug it but take the cable to my (metal)  calipers  rather than the other way round, in case I unplug the wrong thing